# Stored Procedure using in Light Switch

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I want to implement a scenario with light switch. the scenario is like below:

1- create a stored procedure in sql server with 2 input parameters

2- create a form with light switch that provide these 2 input parameters for sp

3- send these 2 parameters with a button in my form to my sp

4- run sp on sql server. this sp return a list of records from db

5- show this returned list from sp in a grid

Is it possible?
If Yes, How can we do this work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you found a way but this is what I do.

I have a web lightswitch app. My form has a button which executes the following

- inserts a line in a table with the parameters you need for your stored procedure
- When the line is inserted, a SQL trigger is executed
- This trigger executes a stored procedure x
- This stored procedure x executes the SSRS job with parameters.

These are the big lines on how to do it. There are a lot of steps but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been out there for a while, but I found this page on MSDN to be very helpful since I was searching for essentially the same thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635144.aspx

Basically, you:

1. Create your stored procedure in SQL Server.
2. Create a dummy table in the intrinsic data of your LS project.
3. Create the UI element (button for instance).
4. Add the element's event handler.  In the handler, you would create a new DB connection using the connection string from the .NET config and run the SP, updating the dummy table with the info from the SP.
5. Link the dummy table to your view as normal.